# cucumber step def waits until a certain value from mongo is "DONE"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, cucumber, cucumberjs

I have a conversion that is started using a service of start conversion.
In mongo I have a field that monitors the conversion status: `ready, runningA, runningB, DONE`.

How can be created a step definition that **wait until the status value of the field from mongo is DONE.**?
If the file to be converted is large, then the conversion will take some minutes(1min ~ 30min).

I don't want to set a fix timer.

The feature is somthing like that:

- `Given` user context
- `When` the user starts the conversion (call the service that starts conversion)
- `Then` the status of the conversion must be done (here I want to wait until the status is done)

Answer (score 0):

You should design your features to reflect your user experience. Here you have a situation where a user can start an action and end up with two (or more) different experiences.

- the conversion happens very quickly and the user can see that the conversion has   completed
- the conversion takes a long time and the user can see that the conversion is underway

So you need at least two different scenarios to deal with this. So lets start with

```
Scenario: Conversion completes immediately
  Given ...
  When I start the conversion
  Then I should see the conversion is completed

Scenario: Conversion will take a long time to complete
  Given ...
  When I start the conversion
  Then I should see the conversion is progressing
```

You probably want to explore things like

`Scenario: Long running conversion has finally completed`

So how does this answer you initial question? Well what it does is translate it into some different equivalent questions. Clearly any useful step definition cannot wait a long time for something to happen. If it does it makes your test suite unusable. So to test long running processes you have to use your Givens to put the process into a particular state that allows you to get an immediate response.

So in your case you would be writing Givens such as

```
Given my conversion has status runningA
Given my conversion has status runningB
...
```

and use those Givens in scenarios that explore the behaviour of your long running process.

From the above we can extract a 'rule of thumb' when cuking,

`Never wait in a Then instead translate the waiting into the thing being done in a Given`

Comment: thank you for your answer! it is helpfull for test design!

Comment: as technical implementation see my step def implementation:

Answer (score 0):

See below my step definition, but I get the timeout
function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 5000 milliseconds

When('the user waits until receive the status DONE',

````
    let start = Date.now()

    function getRunDetailsStaus() {
        return getStatus(runDetailsId) //promise function and returns the status from mongoDB
    }

    function next() {
        return getRunDetailsStaus().then(function (result) {

            console.log("status: ", result.runStatus, Date.now() - start)
            if (status == 'DONE') {
                return status
            }
            else {
                return next()
            }
        })

    }

    return next()
        .then((response) => {
            // process final results
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            //process error
        })
});```
````